# Error in smoothScatter

Tags: r

I've tried to plot a smoothScatter in, my data is correct because I can plot it normally using plot however when I use smoothScatter appears:

> Error in if (!missing(bandwidth) && min(bandwidth) <= 0) stop("'bandwidth' must be strictly positive") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

How can I solve this and what does that mean?

Comment: If you want a specific answer rather than a guess / general description of the error, you'll need to provide the code and data to reproduce the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Just a guess: Try manually specifying the bandwidth. Possibly the function's attempt to select sensible bandwidth is failing. For `smoothScatter`, bandwidth seems to have the same units as your data, so if your range is 1-100, try `bandwidth=2` (smoothing over 2%-wide regions). Also be aware that x and y can have different scales, and therefore need different bandwidths: `bandwidth=c(2, 0.1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It usually means that a logical expression evaluated to NA instead of TRUE or FALSE.

This can be be caused by using the wrong data types, by missing values, or a number of other things.

If you provide a reproducible example then we can give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

set start of xlim "0" instead of other value.